# ObjectListView: елементы, которые содержат картинку, заголовок и описание

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, listview

**ObjectListView WinForms/WPF C#**

Я хочу создать некликабельную таблицу `ObjectListView` как показано на картинке ниже. Но после чтения документации я так и не понял как это сделать.

Может ли кто-то объяснить как сделать хотя бы одну строку из семи?

[image: Image example]

Comment: Переведите на русский, вы на RU.stackoverfow

Comment: @АндрейNOP я перевёл, осталось чтобы кто-то правку принял

Comment: [Тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/b8f4df53-9b58-4b9f-86ea-4d112231f66f/listview-?forum=programminglanguageru) очень похожие примеры. И WinForms, и WPF.

Comment: В wpf можно использовать ItemsControl, в шаблоне элемента может быть при этом все что угодно вам